# Optimizing SQL table creation from a Pyspark dataframe in databricks

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

**Spark DF:** `jrny_df1.createOrReplaceTempView("journeymap_drvs1")`
approx: 10MM records

**Creating a sql table of this view takes a long time:**

```
create table temp.ms_journey_drvsv1 as select * from journeymap_drvs1;
```

Is there any process that I can follow to optimize the speed of the table creation. We Spark 2.4, 88 cores, 671 GB memory

Comment: There are bunch of ways. More partitions, more compute, faster storage... Hard to say without much more details. It might not even be the store part that is slow but the read from source

Answer (score 1):

Check the cluster configuration , post that partition the DF accordingly so that parallaism can be achieved which will eventually reduce the time